# How to stop base styles from being triggered early by media queries?

Tags: css, sass

Is it an anti pattern to include height in media queries when you're aiming for a flexible layout site?

Just writing a mobile first application and I was wondering if it's bad practice to use height inside media tags.

What I've noticed is that including the height in the queries is allowing the style to flow a bit more, whilst including the height simply forces my mobile style (base style) to kick in earlier.

I'm my case, the base styling is a simple one column on mobile with the media queries lookings like this:

```
$desktop-devices-large: "(min-height: 900px) and (max-height: 1080px) and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1920px)";
    $desktop-devices-medium: "(min-height: 768px) and (max-height: 900px) and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1440px)";
    $mobile-devices: "screen and (max-height: 760px) and (max-width: 760px)";
```

I'm using Sass to import the queries so that pattern usually looks like this:

```
.Intro { 
  @extend %section-default;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 100vh;
  padding-left: $spacing-default;
  padding-right: $spacing-default;
  padding-bottom: $spacing-default;
  background-color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url("/assets/images/intro-thumbnail.png");
  background-position: 72% 0%;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 20%;    

@media #{$desktop-devices-large},
      #{$desktop-devices-medium} {
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding-top: $spacing-double;
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        padding-left: $spacing-double;
        padding-right: $spacing-double;
        padding-bottom: $spacing-double;
      }
}
```

I would actually expect the styling to be a bit more forgiving and not trigger the mobile (base styles) too early.

Comment: What do you mean by `not trigger the mobile (base styles) too early.`? Isn't that the idea? Start from the base styles and then built on top of them via media queries?

Comment: @ksav That is the idea, but I'd prefer to have the layout be a bit more forgiving and defining height and width make it too strict. 

Building the breakpoints just on width alone allows the flex containers to grow and shrink for the 'in-between" sizes until a new breakpoint appears.

Comment: So then just use `min-width` in your media queries.